# How to print a specific xml value using python?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have the xml which looks like below

```
<api>
<apicat>
    <cat>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>testname</name>
    </cat>
    <cat>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>testname2</name>
    </cat>
    <cat>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>testname3</name>
    </cat>
</apicat>
```

How to print the name which has id=2?
And also please note that if the xml is not bringing back values in the same order and also if the number of results is higher 10,000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily with [lxml](/questions/tagged/lxml) module with a [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) expression :

```
from lxml import etree

file = "file://path/to/file.xml"
doc = etree.parse(file)

print doc.xpath('//cat[id=2]/name/text()')[0]
```

See http://lxml.de/

and a [Xpath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp)

Your XML file is not valid, this one should be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<api>
    <apicat>
        <cat>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>testname</name>
        </cat>
        <cat>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>testname2</name>
        </cat>
        <cat>
            <id>3</id>
            <name>testname3</name>
        </cat>
    </apicat>
</api>
```

Comment: Since I am new to this, Can you please give me a example for that?

Comment: If you think that the answer is useful, you can 'upvote' it. If you think that the answer is well answerred, you can 'accept' it by clicking the outline of the `checkmark` (will be green), this way, people searching stackexchange website will known that the question is well answered. That's how stackechange websites works, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ xpath -e '//cat[id=2]/name' your.xml
```